# How can I run unattended backups on b2 if the application key needs renewal every day?

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

Backblaze b2 gives me an application key that expires every 24 hours and can only be renewed on the web page. How can I set up unattended backups if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

You use the [b2_authorize_account](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_authorize_account.html) API endpoint or the [command line tool](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/quick_command_line.html) to programmatically generate a token for you when needed.

Comment: The command line tool help says that "The application key is a 40-digit hex number that you can get from your account page on backblaze.com." The `b2_authorize_account` API endpoint also requires the use of the application key, but does not return such a key. I improved the phrasing of the question to make it clear that the problem is the "application key".